# How to backup Sqlite database if sqliteOpenHelper class is used

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.android

I'm quite new in c# and Xamarin android and I want to backup and restore my offline SQLite database created with sqliteOpenHelper Class, send and use that on another device. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Android API sets, the providers for SQLite library are available under, `android.database.sqlite` package. The most prominent types in the package are:

**1. SQLiteOpenHelper**: This is the main class that you need to inherit your classes from, in order to handle the database creation, opening or closing events. Even the events such as create new tables, or deleting the old tables and upgrading your databases to a latest version (such as upgrading the schema), are all handled here in this class-derived classes of yours.

**2. SQLiteDatabase**: This is the object that you get and use to either push the data to the database, or to read the data from the database.

**3. SQLiteCursor**: This is the cursor implementation for working with the data records that are returned after `Query` commands.

The way they all communicate is that, the main class for the data manipulation first of all inherits from `SQLiteOpenHelper`to get the functions to handle, then later has a field of type `SQLiteDatabase`in it to execute the functions for `writing` or `reading` the data.

For more information, you can check: 
https://basicsofwebdevelopment.wordpress.com/2017/02/19/learning-sqlite-databases-in-xamarin-for-android/

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-develop-sqlite-database-using-sqliteopenhelper/